# App Indexing in android

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I have implemented the app indexing in my application but its not working and showing below messages.

Deep link page : http://m.cardekho.com/carmodels/Hyundai/Hyundai_EON

Google could not get all the resources for this page:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/244697749072142/activities?access_token=&format=json&sdk=android
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/244697749072142?format=json&sdk=android&fields=supports_attribution%2Csupports_implicit_sdk_logging%2Cgdpv4_nux_content%2Cgdpv4_nux_enabled
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/244697749072142?format=json&sdk=android&fields=supports_attribution%2Csupports_implicit_sdk_logging%2Cgdpv4_nux_content%2Cgdpv4_nux_enabled
https://track.appsflyer.com/api/v2.3/androidevent?buildnumber=1.15&app_id=com.girnarsoft.cardekho

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to resources which are either disallowed for crawling, or can't be accessed, but are deemed important for the page structure. In this case it's the former.

At https://graph.facebook.com/robots.txt it's currently showing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

To work around this, you would either convince Facebook to remove the disallow line so clients can access those resources, or you could modify the app so it relies less on the roboted (disallowed) resources.